# Redisplay system tray icons in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, icons

1. I have some apps that have icons in system tray (bottom right part of the screen).
2. I kill Explorer, because I had some problems with it or not
3. I start Explorer once again via Task Manager
4. The system tray icons are missing but the apps are running

Is there a way to redisplay system tray icons in the above situation?

Answer (score 1):

Only rebooting works consistently for that issue.

After restarting Explorer, it is possible to kill one of the systray applications, such as Windows Defender GUI (`C:\Windows\System32\SecurityHealthSystray.exe`) in *Task Manager* and then restart the app: the icon *might* show again in the tray... and sometimes, *might not*. sigh

If you want to restart applications, [Sysinternals' *Process Explorer*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) makes the chore easier than with *Task Manager* because it has a context menu item to do it in one swell foop.

Only rebooting works consistently for that issue, but try logging out (switching user) and logging in again, which is faster.